# Why is materialize not responsive on my phone?

Tags: android, css, google-apps-script, mobile, materialize

I'm designing a web app using Google Apps Script and I want to use MaterializeCSS for styling. It looks great on desktop and tablet, but it is incredibly small on my Android phone. To demonstrate the issue with barebones code, I've got this HTML that is pulled from MaterializeCss.com

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input disabled value="I am not editable" id="disabled" type="text" class="validate">
              <label for="disabled">Disabled</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
              This is an inline input field:
              <div class="input-field inline">
                <input id="email_inline" type="email" class="validate">
                <label for="email_inline">Email</label>
                <span class="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Helper text</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Please note that there is a meta viewport tag in the header. In my research, this is what everyone lists as a solution. Here's the result I'm getting from this code on my phone:

[image]

And when I tap inside a textbox, the entire screen appears to go blank.

[image]

This apparent blank screen is actually the result of being zoomed in by materialize. Very strange! Can someone help me to understand what is going on with this weird mobile phone issue?

Comment: Please add the name and version of the web browser that you are using and the screen size and resolution of your Android phone.

Comment: @Rubén Is there a reason you minified the original images in this question?

Comment: @TheMaster They took much space causing to much scrolling.... I found no reason to have the images that big.